# Angular material multiple items drag drop

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material for dragging an item from one list to other.

Attaching the code: https://stackblitz.com/angular/mdgkpprxjej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.ts.

My issue is that I'm able to move only a single item across the lists. Is there some way to select and drag multiple items?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is achievable. However, it requires too much work. You can take a look at  [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13807#issuecomment-568682335). KevynTD explained well to achieve this using Angular cdk.

Comment: Yes, That's quite complex. I'm looking for something simple. But, I can still give a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy way...